# Conjure-up kubernetes removes zfs definition

Tags: lxc, zfs, conjure-up

Installing the Canonical distribution of Kubernetes removes the LXC zfs definition forcing writes to dir

Before conjure-up the "lxc info" command says:

`...snip...
config: 
 storage.zfs_pool_name: lxd 
apiextensions: 
- id_map 
apistatus: stable 
...snip...
serverversion: 2.0.9 
 storage: zfs 
 storageversion: "5"`

After conjure-up completes correctly (I can see the kubernetes dashboard and the juju gui) the storage is forced to dir

The command "lxc info" says:

`...snip...
config:
  core.https_address: '[::]'
  storage.zfs_pool_name: lxd
api_extensions:
- storage_zfs_remove_snapshots
- container_host_shutdown_timeout
...snip...
  server_pid: 5149
  server_version: "2.11"
  storage: dir
  storage_version: "1"`

and the zpool command says thar there was no read and no writes:

`sysop@vx07:~$ sudo zpool status
[sudo] password di sysop: 
  pool: lxd
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:`

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    lxd         ONLINE       0     0     0
      vdb1      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

errors: No known data errors
sysop@vx07:~$

What can I do to force conjure-up to use the zfs backend?

Comment: So we have control over the disk pool with a custom lxd-profile seen here: https://github.com/conjure-up/spells/blob/master/canonical-kubernetes/steps/lxd-profile.yaml#L20-L23 What I think needs to happen is you can either create a copy of that spell and update the profile to use your zfs setup or we need to come up with a better way to let users customize localhost deployments including modifying the lxd profile.